# Trying to connect a NodeJS app to MongoDB via Docker Compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm following a MongoDB + NodeJS tutorial with my app.  Everything works without Docker.. and I can in fact get the app to work up until it needs to connect to MongoDB.

If my app doesn't see MongoDB, it will print out an error and halt.

Here's my files

.env

```
NODE_VIEWS_PATH=../
NODE_PUBLIC_PATH=../
MONGODB_URI='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myappsdb'
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/mahrio

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

EXPOSE 6085

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: someappname
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "6085:6085"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: You don't need to use `links` in version 2+ compose files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using docker-compose, for a container to connect to another container it can use the service name as a hostname to connect.

In your case, the node app needs to connect to `mongo:27017` rather than `localhost:27017`, since localhost from the respective of the app container will refer to itself and not to your machine.

Therefore, change the mongo url to `MONGODB_URI='mongodb://mongo:27017/myappsdb'`. Also make sure that you consume the env file by adding:

```
app:
 ...
 env_file:
   - file.env
```

Comment: this .env file is shared with npm and node.. I don't think it would work to change the `mongodb_URI` like this , but I'll try it temp.

Comment: the mongodb connected, but when I goto the `localhost:6085` nothing happens (acts like it cannot see a server there)